Proof that the finite-dimensional extension $K[a]$ coincides with the decomposition field $K(a)$

Let $K\subseteq F$ be an extended field and $a\in F$. Let $K[a]=\left \{ f(a)|f\in K[x] \right \}$. Prove that if $K[a]$ is finite-dimensional as a vector space over $K$, then $K[a]=K(a)$

Consider the set $ \{1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^n\} $. Let $ n $ be the dimension of $ K[a] $ as a vector space over $ K $. This means that $ 1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^n $ are linearly dependent elements in $ K[a] $. Consequently, there exists a nonzero polynomial $ f(x) \in K[x] $ of degree at most $ n $ such that $ f(a) = 0 $. Let $ f(x) = c_n x^n + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_0 $, where $ c_i \in K $ and $ f(a) = 0 $. Since $f(a) = 0$, this means that $a$ is the root of the polynomial $f(x)$. Thus $a$ is an algebraic element over $K$. The minimal polynomial $a$ over $K$ is a divisor of $f(x)$ and has the same degree as $f(x)$. Let us denote the minimal polynomial $ a $ as $ m(x) $. Thus $ K(a) $ is the decomposition field for $ m(x) $. The field $ K(a) $ consists of all elements of the form $ g(a) / h(a) $, where $ g(x), h(x) \in K[x] $ and $ h(a) \neq $0. However, since $ m(a) = 0 $ and the degree of $ m(x) $ does not exceed $ n $, any such relation can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements $ \{1, a, a^2, \ldots, a ^{n-1}\} $. Due to the finite-dimensionality of the space $ K[a] $ over $ K $, each element of $ K(a) $ can be expressed as a linear combination of $ 1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^{n-1} $, which means that $ K(a) \subseteq K[a] $
Conversely, by definition, $ K[a] \subseteq K(a) $, since each element of $ K[a] $ is $ f(a) $ for some $ f \in K[x] $, which is an element from $ K(a) $
I have not encountered such problems, so I tried to prove it using elementary algebra and definitions. I don't know how to prove this in a smart way (I would be glad if someone showed me a smart way)
I would like to ask if I applied the theory and definitions correctly in the proof?

Let $K$ be a field, $F$ the field extension of $K$. Let $a$ be some element of the field $F$

$K[a]$ is the smallest subring of the field $F$, which contains the field $K$ and the element $a$

$K(a)$ is the smallest field that contains the field $K$ and the element $a$, or formally speaking, it is the smallest subfield of the field $F$ that contains the field $K$ and the element $a$


Suppose that $K[a]$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $K$. It follows from the definition that $K[a]$ is contained in $K(a)$, because $K[a]$ is the smallest subring, and $K(a)$ is the smallest subfield, and the subfield is automatically a subring too it is forced to contain the smallest subring
We need to prove the reverse inclusion, but to prove this we only need to show that $K[a]$ is a field. This is a kind of commutative ring with unity without non-trivial divisors. Let us use the finite-dimensionality condition, since $K[a]$ is finite-dimensional over the field $K$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\left \{ 1,a,a^2,\ldots a^n \right \}$ is a linearly dependent system of elements over the field $K$. Let's choose such $n$ and we get that we have some non-trivial linear combination
$$\lambda _0+\lambda _1a+\lambda _2a^2 +\ldots \lambda _na^n=0,$$
where $\lambda _0,\lambda _1,\ldots, \lambda _n$ are elements of the field $K$. Consequently, the element $a$ is algebraic over $K$, that is, this element has a minimal polynomial $m$ irreducible. Every element $K[a]$ can be represented as $f(a)$ (a certain polynomial with coefficients from the field $K$). If $f(a)$ is nonzero, then the polynomial $f(x)$ is not divisible by $m(x)$. This means that there are polynomials $s$ and $t$ such that $s(x)f(x)+t(x)m(x)=1$, we substitute $a$ and get $s(a)f(a )=1$, it follows that $f(a)$ is invertible. Hence $K[a]$ is a field
